# Specific law/regulation about annual report and other shareholder information disclosure in Canada

Tags: canada, finance

As I understand it, when you hold shares of a publicly traded company (or ETF) via a broker, the broker is obligated to forward you the relevant investor information from the company (e.g. annual report, share voting documents, and more). I've seen this done in both snail-mail and electronic form.

My question is: What specific laws and/or regulations in Canada talk about the broker's obligation to forward this information? (If the answer is province-specific, I'd appreciate an answer for Ontario.)